# Does a Constitutional Amendment Overruling a Court Decision Reinstate Any Applicable Laws?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-constitution

Suppose the Supreme Court of the United States rules on an issue of a federal law and decides that a certain law is unconstitutional and cannot be enforced.

Then suppose Congress proposes an amendment to the states to amend the constitution to remove the language that made the law unconstitutional. This amendment is then ratified and becomes part of the constitution.

Does this in turn make the original law enforceable again? Or does Congress have to pass the law again in order for it to be enforceable?

Essentially my question is if the doctrine of stare decisis (or similar doctrine) prevents the enforcement of the old law until a new law is passed after adoption of the constitutional amendment.

Additionally, as there may be limited federal examples, I would be interested in similar situations which occur during interpretations of state constitutions.

Comment: The question as applied to states is more likely to have an answer (so I suggest making it more prominent). At the federal level, I don't believe the situation has ever arisen, so one can only speculate.

Comment: @user6726 I would also be interested authorities like law review articles and similar

Comment: Instead of an amendment what about changing constitutional interpretation? There's currently wide discussion on this point with current pushes to overturn Roe v. Wade and "reactivating" unenforced law.

Answer (score 1):

Stare Decisis does not validate an old law that was struck down.  Rather it allows the creation of a similar but still new law.  You cannot be prosecuted for a crime committed before a law takes effect.  Since the constitution is the Supreme Law of the land, any law that is Unconstitutional is an illegal law, thus the criminalized act is still legal.

There is historical precedence for this:  With the passage of the 18th amendment (Prohibition) alcohol was not criminalized per se, right off the bat.  Rather, it empowered Congress to pass the Volstead Act, which was the regulatory act that banned the substance.  When the 21st amendment was ratified, repealing the 18th Amendment, the Volstead act was automatically repealed as it was now illegal under the Constitution.

In a similar possible future situation, the hypothetical repeal of the Second Amendment would not make firearm ownership illegal, as all gun control laws in existance currently are 2nd Amendment compliant.  To make firearm ownership illegal a specific law would need to be passed to make firearms owership illegal.  Repealing the 2nd Amendment only removes the Constitutional block saying that such a law is unconstitutional.

Comment: I don't believe your answer fully addresses my question: what I am asking is if there is a law on the books that is patently unconstitutional, but then the reason for its unconstitutionality is removed, does it become enforceable again?

Comment: (To address your ex post facto argument, I mean acts an individual commits after the passage of the constitutional amendment that violate the old law, which was previously ruled unconstitutional, but is now not unconstitutional)

Comment: Old Law (A) would not automatically go into effect without being re-ratified as New Law (B).  In your scenario, A was decided not to be a valid law by SCOTUS because it violated the Constitution (present 27).  Thus when the Constitution (future 28th) is changed, A is still not the law.  The impediment that made A unconstitutional is now gone, but A was effectively disappeared from criminal codes.  The one exception might be Laws were only say Article 3 out of 8 Articles was struck down, but that just means 3 was never passed, while 1,2 and 4-8 still remain.

Comment: do you have any citations to support that claim?

Comment: @Viktor:  From American Jurisprudence:

The general rule is that an unconstitutional statute, though having the form and the name of law, is in reality no law, but is wholly void and ineffective for any purpose since unconstitutionality dates from the time of its enactment and not merely from the date of the decision so branding it; an unconstitutional law, in legal contemplation, is as inoperative as if it had never been passed ... An unconstitutional law is void. (16 Am. Jur. 2d, Sec. 178)

Comment: @Viktor:  Furthermore, since the constitution defines the powers and limits of the U.S. Government, the Government and Only the Government can be found in violation of Constitutional Law.  This is why the 18th Amendment needed the passage of the Volstead Act to be enforced AND why private entities can enact Speech Codes that would violate the First Amendment if the Government passed a similar law.

Comment: @hszmv It isn't clear (at least to me) that the passage you quoted actually answers the question either way. It is talking about unconstitutional laws. The law in question is specifically stated to be a constitutionally valid law. There is no conflict between the constitution and the law. Sure, the law was void as soon as it was passed, but it isnt clear to me that this means it continues to be void when there is no longer a constitutional conflict.Do you have a source that further elaborates on the treatment of this particular example? Or perhaps an example of this particular situation?

Comment: And how would that work? Congress usually amends the USC when it passes laws, but an overruling by a court doent actually change the code, (or does it?) just makes part unenforceable. Does congress just pass a bill saying "USC section 284 now reads exactly what it currently reads", and the law is back?

Comment: @Matt:  Essentially what is said is that a law in sync with the constitution is still a law.  A law in some disagreement with the constitution is invalid for the purposes of the portion that is unconstitutional.  Functionally, it is treated as having never passed at all, so if the Constitution was amended to make that law compliant with the Constitution, then a new bill will need to be passed to bring the original back into effect.

Comment: @Matt:  With respect to the USC, while they do not remove the numbering of the laws, when a law is repealed or struck down, the law itself is deleted and replaced with historical footnotes to explain the nature of the previous law for the purposes of reference for historical case work.  Thus, while a struck law section remains there, the law does not, merely a description of what used to be there.  So a bill described by you would more likely validate the historical note than actually re-enact a once existing law.

Comment: @Viktor: I don't know of any specific ruling, but state legislatures generally believe that law on the books that is currently unconstitutional becomes in force should the situation change and the law become constitutional.